# R. replacing null value representation with NA

Tags: r, csv, na

I have tried all the methods that I have found on stackoverflow regarding this topic and nothing worked.

Here is a sample of my dataset called TEST:

```
x2000 x2001 x2002

100   1200   230
200   2002   280
:     1980   :
```

":" represents a missing value. The problem is that I cannot replace this colon with R-accepted NA.

What I have tried:

```
sum(TEST %in c(":"))
returns: [1] 0

TEST[TEST==":"] <-NA #does nothing
```

I tried to save the file as .csv, replace the values with "NA" in excel and it still does nothing. The columns are not factors. if the column contains the value of ":" then the column is "chr" otherwise it is "int".

Comment: You should give a reproducible example. `TEST[TEST==":"] <-NA` should work, but without a reproducible example we can't tell you why it doesn't.

Comment: As pointed out by @RichardScriven the code should work. I suspect that the problem is how you import the data. Maybe you are reading the file with `read.csv()`? If yes, try to use `read.table(filename, header=TRUE)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest method is to set the na.strings method when reading in the data with one of the `read.` family of functions. Here is an example with `read.table` for your example data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="x2000 x2001 x2002
100   1200   230
200   2002   280
:     1980   :  ", na.strings=":")
```

This returns

```
df
  x2000 x2001 x2002
1   100  1200   230
2   200  2002   280
3    NA  1980    NA
```

Perhaps more importantly, the structure of the resulting data.frame is vectors of integers:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x2000: int  100 200 NA
 $ x2001: int  1200 2002 1980
 $ x2002: int  230 280 NA
```

Without this, you will end up with a mixture of integer vectors and factor variables, which complicates the cleaning process a bit.